# Unable to retrieve ReplyToAddress & ReplyToDisplayName

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am not able to retrieve `ReplyToAddress` & `ReplyToDisplayName` from TriggeredSendDefinition.

Currently, I have successfully retrieved `FromAddress` & `FromName` from `TriggeredSendDefinition` using the following SSJS

```
var triggeredSendCustomerKey = '12345'
var cols = ["CustomerKey", "Name", "FromAddress", "FromName"];
var filter = {
    Property: "CustomerKey",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: triggeredSendCustomerKey
};
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var desc = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);
```

But once I added extra cols - "ReplyToAddress" & "ReplyToDisplayName" - and run it via Cloudpages, I got an Error 500

```
var cols = ["CustomerKey", "Name", "FromAddress", "FromName", "ReplyToAddress", "ReplyToDisplayName"];
```

I also failed retrieving them using `SenderProfile`. I was able to printed the result and I got the following message:

```
{ "Status": "Error: The Request Property(s) ReplyToAddress,ReplyToDisplayName do not match with the fields of SenderProfile retrieve", ...
```

Anyone is able to retrieve them or if you spotted any issue of my code, please kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the error is in your code.

This is reproducible via plain SOAP API (which is what WSProxy is based on but "transforms", format-wise)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>TriggeredSendDefinition</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Description</Properties>
                <Properties>ReplyToDisplayName</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

returns:

```
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) ReplyToDisplayName do not match with the fields of TriggeredSendDefinition retrieve</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>1c2518d5-1429-4dde-9d3f-40d2fec6a8ee</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

for both your extra cols respectively. Tried it for SenderProfile, TriggeredSendDefinition, EmailSendDefinition with the same results. Remove that `<Properties>` node and it works.

These are all the objects from the docs where replyToAddress appears. So it looks like the documentation is not correct: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/senddefinition.html?q=replytoaddress

It seems like you have to change the approach. What I can think of is this (Of course, this will only work going forward):

log the following personalization strings (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) at time of send and retrieve them from the log.

```
%%replyname%% - Your reply name, as defined in your account settings
%%replyemailaddress%% - Your reply email address
```

Comment: Thanks for your time verifying this in SOAP. I love your advice for using SendLog as an option so I market it as answer. Unfortunately it does not work in my use case as I would need the data before the send happen.